# Custom shortcuts from bluetooth headset media controls

Tags: bluetooth, shortcuts

I have a bluetooth headset hooked up to my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop and the media control buttons (play/pause/etc) work for VLC, but I **NEED** it to work with YouTube.  And while that's the ultimate goal, the first step, I think, is to capture/recognize the button press in order to set up a custom shortcut and I can't even get that far.

I wish I could say I found some useful info, but all the search terms I could think of gave me answers about turning bluetooth on and off and other unrelated questions.  Even if somebody could give me some suggestions for specific search terms, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Nobody? What about a camera remote trigger that works over bluetooth?  That might bet me on the right path?